# Unable to load lua dll with gvim 8 (Windows)

Tags: windows, vim, lua, vi, vim-plugin

This is with reference to the [Vim plugin neocomplete](https://github.com/Shougo/neocomplete.vim) which requires Vim to be compiled with lua.

I downloaded the Vim 8.0.0347 official x64 build for windows compiled with lua from [here](http://vim-jp.org/redirects/)

I downloaded the lua53.dll from [here](http://lua-users.org/wiki/LuaBinaries) and placed the .dll and .exe and placed it alongside my gvim.exe.

Here is the screenshot for my :version [image]

But :echo has("lua") returns 0

and :lua print("hello") returns [image]

What else do I need?

Comment: Prabably, when gvim is working, its current directory is not the same as `gvim.exe` directory. Try to copy `lua53.dll` to any directory in your `%PATH%`.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff I tried putting into c:\windows\system32\ but that too didn't work

Comment: Probably you should find 64-bit Lua dll

Comment: Thanks a lot sir. I was using 32 bit dll for 64 bit vim. Stupid me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was using 32 bit lua.dll for my 64 bit vim. That's plain wrong. Hope this helps somebody.